# Unable to build / debug iOS Cordova App via remotebuild and Visual Studio 2015

Tags: ios, error-handling, visual-studio-cordova

I had remotebuild setup and working and had successfully created a production IPA. I have since tried to update the project and am now presented with the the following from Visual Studio when I run a debug on remote ios device:

> Remote build error from the build server Build failed with error
>   ENOENT, no such file or directory
>   '/Users/Dev/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/1707/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/MyApp/config.xml

The project files are copied over the to Mac and saved fine. The XCode project will itself open OK and build though the /platforms/ios/MyApp directory is not created as part of the build from VS

Where the application name is "MyApp"

Any thoughts or suggestions on this would be greatly appreciated

Thanks,

David Marshall

Comment: From the error message, the config.xml is missing from your project. Can you reproduce this problem on a new blank project? And also try clearing the cordova cache under VS->tools->options->Tools for Apache Cordova->Clear Cordova Cache.

Comment: Updating the comments here until we have a workaround (I'm part of the Visual Studio Cordova tools team) - we've found a bug that seems to be causing this issue. We'll update everyone here when we have a workaround/fix.

Comment: One workaround for now: use Cordova v6.0.0 as your target Cordova version. This looks like an issue with Cordova v6.1.0.

Comment: Jordan, thanks for the rapid response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some investigation, it turns out that this issue is related to Cordova bug [CB-10961](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10961). To fix it, you have to either upgrade your project to Cordova 6.1.1, or revert to 6.0.0. I'd recommend going to 6.1.1 since it is a minor update of 6.1.0, primarily with bug fixes.

Comment: Jordan thanks for your efforts here - the solution to switch to 6.1.1 worked for me. I will add that in my case I had to clear down my projects temporary files to get things building again. Shout out to Jimmy Thomson on the VS Cordova Tools dev team for his help and support